# Using variables in citation commands

Tags: biblatex, macros

I'm trying to simplify a process of having to manually type a citation command multiple times. I'd like to type it once in a variable, and then the `cite` command will read the variable multiple times; this will save me a lot of manual typing.  What I'm trying to do is best illustrated with the example below. Any advice?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear,sorting=nyt]{biblatex} 

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{test,
        author = {Author},
        title = {Title},
        journaltitle = {Annalen der Physik},
        year = {1905},
        volume = {322},
        number = {10},
        pages = {891--921},
        abstract = {Abstract}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\citeKey}{test}

%outputs the text `test'
\citeKey{}

%this works
\cite{test} \\
\citetitle{test} \\
\citefield{test}{abstract} 

%this does not work
\cite{\citeKey{}} \\
\citetitle{\citeKey{}} \\
\citefield{\citeKey{}}{abstract} 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try without the `{}`?

Comment: Why the `{}`? It seems to work without them... As egreg just said :P

Comment: Thanks. Removing the `{}` works. Simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `{}` bits that are just for *printing* the expansion of the command honoring a following space, but are not part of the syntax.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{test,
        author = {Author},
        title = {Title},
        journaltitle = {Annalen der Physik},
        year = {1905},
        volume = {322},
        number = {10},
        pages = {891--921},
        abstract = {Abstract}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\citeKey}{test}

%outputs the text `test'
\citeKey{}

%this works
\cite{test} \\
\citetitle{test} \\
\citefield{test}{abstract} 

%this does not work
\cite{\citeKey} \\
\citetitle{\citeKey} \\
\citefield{\citeKey}{abstract} 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

I recommend removing also `backend=bibtex`: `biblatex` works much better with `biber`.

Comment: Thanks. I use `backend=bibtex` because I'm typically compiling using`knitr` via Rstudio which doesn't support `biber`